# HIbernate Envers: foreign key to revision

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

Is it possible to add a foreign key to a revision of an entity?

For example if I have the entity `Person`:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column
    private Integer idPerson;
    @Column
    private String favoriteHobby;
}
```

I would like to point to a revision of a person. Let's say I create a yearbook and I would like it to contain the favorite hobby of that person at the moment, but if the person would update his/her favorite hobby afterwards, I want the yearbook to contain the old hobby.

In SQL, this would be accomplished by creating a table with the columns `idPerson`, `idRevision` and `idYearBook`.

But I'm not sure if and how I can translate this into an entity, query it, create my yearbook... without writing custom queries or duplication my person entity.

Comment: Is a `YearBook` considered immutable in your data model?  If so, if you can identify the specific year book you're after, you can then traverse to all associated `Person` and get the information you seek.

Comment: @Naros you mean that if I would make both `Person` and `YearBook` audited, I would be able to get an archived Yearbook and traverse to all Persons that were at that moment linked to that Yearbook in their current state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question from the comments first, Yes.

If you marked both entities as `@Audited`, any change you make to either entity would result in a new audit row being created in the audit schema for that specific entity.

The `AuditReader` API mimics much of the old legacy Hibernate Criteria API.  You basically can build any query based on an audited entity type and apply a plethora of conditions on which to filter the results.

There is one caveat here I want to mention.

Lets assume in a transaction, we create a `Person` and put them in the `YearBook`:

```
final Session session = openSession();
try {
   session.getTransaction().begin();

   final Person person = new Person();
   person.setName( "John Doe" );
   person.setHobby( "Plays Guitar" );
   session.save( person );

   final YearBook yearBook = new YearBook();
   yearBook.setYear( 2018 );
   yearBook.getPeople().add( person );
   session.save( yearBook );

   session.getTransaction().commit();
}
catch( Exception ex ) {
   if ( session.getTransaction().isActive() ) {
     session.getTransaction().rollback();
   }
   throw ex;
}
finally {
  session.close();
}
```

This would mean that in the audit schema, a new audit row would be created for both of these entity types and those rows would be associated to the same revision number.  For simplicity sake, lets say that is revision number **1**.

In a future transaction, you modify `Person` for this *John Doe*:

```
final Session session = openSession();
try {
  session.getTransaction().begin();

  final Person person = session.find( Person.class, personId );
  person.setHobby( "Video Games" );

  session.getTransaction().commit();
}
catch( Exception ex ) {
   if ( session.getTransaction().isActive() ) {
     session.getTransaction().rollback();
   }
   throw ex;
}
finally {
  session.close();
}
```

At this point:

- `YearBook` as a single revision, revision #**1**.
- `Person` for *John Doe* has two revisions, revisions #**1** and #**2**.

The caveat here is that queries against `YearBook` for revision **1** will never return you anything about `Person` in revision **2**.  This is definitely the desired result in almost all cases; however there are some unique situations where users want `YearBook` to trigger a revision too.

If you want the collection owner to also generate a revision when an element attribute is modified that doesn't impact the state of the collection itself, you'll need to place a dummy attribute on the container and modify it as a part of the transaction so both get audited.

That said, how would you go about getting `YearBook` at its revisions?  That's pretty straight forward using the `AuditReader` API:

```
final AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get( session );

// Get the revisions in ascending order from smallest to highest rev #
List<Number> revisions = reader
  .forRevisionsOfEntity( YearBook.class, false )
  .getResultList();
```

If you already know the revision number that you're interested in, you can then get the exact snapshot of that entity using:

```
final AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get( session );
final YearBook yearBook = reader.find( YearBook.class, yearBookId, revision );
```

Check out the documentation for all the other ways to create queries using the `AuditReader` interface provided by Envers.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! My current solution is to duplicate my Person entity (as in taking a snapshot) and point to that snapshot. It's not that pretty as your solution, but it gives me more control on when I want to make a snapshot. I also wonder what happens if you would update the `YearBook` after having edited the `Person`. I guess the yearBook would be on revision #3. But would it still point to the persons in revision #1?

Comment: Ah wait a second. That's the reason that you asked me if `YearBook` is immutable? It's not very clear from the documentation and I should test this more in detail, but I guess that the yearBook on #3 will then point to the linked persons on #3 (or maybe #2 if the update is not cascaded). In my case `YearBook` is not immutable, so I'll have to stay with my own solution. A bit sad since I now have duplicate entities which are very similar. (I tried to use inheritence, but that caused problems with my meta model generations, but that's a different problem.)

Comment: That's correct.  Anytime you modify `YearBook` it is considered a new "snapshot" of the object model so at that point any changes you've made to `Person` entities since the prior revision of `YearBook` will now be included when you fetch revision that is being generated.  In other words, it creates a _snapshot of the entity object model_ and not just the specific entity.

Comment: I do believe the cleanest way here is to likely use multiple entity models to represent the data you want.  For example, you could audit `YearBook` and `Person` to capture all the changes made to them.  You could then have two other entity types, `YearBook2` and `Person2` where you replicate changes to those based on some business rules and audit those too.  You end up with the best of both worlds with having every change tracked in one model and the snapshots tracked based on some business rules in another.